# Наибольшая цифра трехзначного числа

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите по коду, не могу разобраться, где неправильно, у меня иногда в программе неправильно показывает наибольшую цифру трехзначного числа. Программа составлена по заданию:

> Создать программу, выводящую на экран случайно сгенерированное трёхзначное натуральное
> число и его наибольшую цифру.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        final int min = 100;
        final int max = 999;
        int first;
        int second;
        int third;
        int value_max;
        int value = (int) (min + Math.random() * (max - min)) ;
        if(value > min && value < max) {
            first = (int) Math.floor(value / 100);
            second = (int) Math.floor((value - first * 100) / 10);
            third = (int) Math.floor(value - first * 100 - second * 10);
            System.out.println("Трехзначное число = "  + value);
            if(first > second) {
                value_max = first;
                if(value_max < third) {
                    value_max = third;
                } else {
                    value_max = second;
                }

            } else {
                value_max = second;
            }
            if(value_max < third)
                value_max = third;
            System.out.println("Первое число = "  + first);
            System.out.println("Второе число = "  + second);
            System.out.println("Третье число = "  + third);
            System.out.println("Максимальное число = "  + value_max);

        }
    }
}
```

И еще такой вопрос, по какой формуле можно также вычислить наибольшую цифру четырех и пятизначного числа и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int min = 100; 
    final int max = 999; 
    int value = (int) (min + Math.random() * (max - min)); 
    int value_max = 0;
    int digit;

    System.out.println(value);

    do {
        digit = value%10;
        if ( digit > value_max ) value_max=digit;

        value = (value - digit)/10;

    } while (value > 0);
    System.out.println(value_max);
}
```

}

Comment: Работает для любого количества чисел, единственное, можно не отнимать значение `digit` если уверены, что value будет приведено к типу int

Comment: по сишной традиции не уверен

Comment: Отнимать точно не надо (ни в Си, ни в Яве)

Comment: Фразу "не надо" можно понять как "неправильно". с точки зрения понятности алгоритма лучше будет так, как я написал. Потому что алгоритм такой:
десятичное число раскладываем (abc) = (a*10+b)*10+c
откуда 
c = (abc)%c
b = ((abc) - c)%10
a = ((ab) - b)%10
и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще логика для чисел любой значности такова. Допустим есть 3 числа, берем первое, и считаем что оно максимальное, сравниваем его со вторым, если 1-е больше, то сравниваем с третим, если нет, то второе считаем максимальным и сравниваем с третим. Опять же, если второе больше, то оно и есть максимальное из всех, если меньше, то максимальное - третье.

В Яве я не силен, но на PHP это делается элементарно одной функцией min(), а если без ее использования но следуя логике, описанной выше это делается так:

```
<?php
function min_ch($ch){
  $min = $ch[0];
  foreach ($ch as $key=>$val){
     if ($min < $val) {
        continue;
     } else {
        $min = $val;    
     }
  }
  echo $min;
}
?>
```

В данной функции меняя знак < на знак > можно находить соответственно минимальное и максимальное число в исходном массиве.

Comment: Demos, подскажите, пожалуйста, если я хочу найти наименьшую цифру из любого числа, то по какой логике оно работает, опишите?

Comment: Ну, так же, как я и написал, только с точностью да наоборот. Считаем 1-е минимальным, сравниваем со вторым, если 1-е меньше, сравниваем с третим, если больше, то считаем второе минимальным и сравниваем с третим. Если 2-е больше, то минимальное из всех 3-е, если меньше, то второе минимальное.

Answer (score 2):

У вас не рассмотрен вариант, когда цифры равные. 
Лучше так:

```
value_max = first;
    if(value_max < second) { 
    value_max = second;
    }
      if (value_max < third) {
        value_max = third;
      }
```